# C# string formatting and padding

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting

Seems like this should be something straightforward, but I haven't been able to get it right. I've looked at http://idunno.org/archive/2004/14/01/122.aspx for reference.

Example:
I would like to print a table of double values, with each double output having 3 decimal precision, and take up 10 spaces (left aligned). Conceptually, I tried something like this, but it only works with precision OR padding, not both:

```
foreach(line in lines)
{
    foreach (double val in line)
    {
         Console.Write("{0:0.000,-10}", val);
    }

    Console.WriteLine()
}
```

Update: I can use padleft/padright in very simple scenarios, if i have more complicated output it becomes not very concise. Is there something similar to sprintf?

Comment: string.Format is C#'s sprintf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
double d = 3.14;
Console.WriteLine("{0,10:0.000}", d);
```

P.S: have a look at [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/kathykam/archive/2006/03/29/564426.aspx) as a primer on string formatting. Also, `string.Format` should allow you doing everything sprintf does - and actually more... what else are you trying to do?

Comment: :) very nice! thanks
ah my fault for not reading the description more carefully

Answer (score 1):

useful

`|{0,-10:0.00}| => |87,87   | - With "-"` => padRight

`|{0,10:0.000}| => |  87,878| - Without "-"` => padLeft

`|{3,-10:0.###}| - ###` - prints numbers after decimal "," only if it is meaningful (not 0): 87,8000 =>87,8